# ERROR: command "pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2" failed

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting an error when I try to install Gphoto2 on my windows pc.

I have tried installing following the instructions from https://pypi.org/project/gphoto2/ and downloading the zip from git clone https://github.com/jim-easterbrook/python-gphoto2.git but have had no success.

This module is supposed to install successfully.

Using the PYPI https://pypi.org/project/gphoto2/ 
I have tried to follow and install this module also downloading and installing the zip from:
git clone https://github.com/jim-easterbrook/python-gphoto2.git

I have had great difficulty, any advice or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\python-gphoto2-master\python-gphoto2-master> python setup.py install
ERROR: command "pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2" failed
```

This module Gphoto2 is supposed to install successfully.

This is what the complete error says:

```
C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\python-gphoto2-master\python-gphoto2-master> 
python setup.py install ERROR: command "pkg-config --modversion 
libgphoto2" failed Traceback (most recent call last): File "setup.py", 
line 36, in <module> cmd, stderr=FNULL, 
universal_newlines=True).split('.') File 
"C:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output process = 
Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs) Windows: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: This is what the complete error says:                          C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\python-gphoto2-master\python-gphoto2-master> python setup.py install
ERROR: command "pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2" failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 36, in <module>
    cmd, stderr=FNULL, universal_newlines=True).split('.')
  File "C:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)   
Windows: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question and include the error message from the comment. If you put > before the error it will format it as a quote, and you can add two spaces to the ends of lines to cause them to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of python-gphoto2.

Python-gphoto2 is not expected to work on Windows. The PyPI page (https://pypi.org/project/gphoto2/) shows the supported operating systems - MacOS and POSIX compatible (e.g. Linux).

I have been able to install it in MSYS2 (http://www.msys2.org/) but it isn't useful unless you get Windows to use libusb instead of its normal driver for your camera.

Comment: Hi Jim, Yes the only way around this is to create a virtual machine on your windows computer and run linux on it. Doing this I am able to connect the camera and interface with Octoprint. See links below for more info:

Comment: Use to add virtual machine install: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBSSGmZU7Bc&t=2s  & How to install Octoprint using Linux:

https://youtu.be/fimVwRXarf4 & Using a DSLR with Octolapse

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5SskYwP5JQ&t=457s

Comment: I have the exact same error but on a raspberry PI (Debian Linux).  I ran the failed command in the error mesage:
    pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2
and got the errors below:
Package libgphoto2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libgphoto2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libgphoto2' found

Comment: I found the answer on the raspberry PI forum.  Need to run sudo apt install libgphoto2-dev first.

Comment: Raspberry Pi is a Linux machine. The original question was about Windows, where the only way to use libgphoto2 is MSYS2. The python-gphoto2 README is quite clear about the need to install the "dev" package.
https://github.com/jim-easterbrook/python-gphoto2#dependencies

Comment: It seems libusb may be used on windows https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/Windows